# Java List.get.addAll not working as expected

Tags: java

I would like to know as why when I do list.get.addAll it does not works but works with list.set
Here is my code

```
@Data
class EmployeeSearchRespoonse{
    
    private List<Emplyoee> employeeList;

    private List<Error> statusList;


      public List<Error> getErrors(){
        if(errors==null){
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return errors;

    }

    public List<Employee> getEmployeeList(){
    if(employeeList==null){
     return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    return employeeList;
    }

}
```

Method where I am using this

```
    public EmployeeSearchRespoonse retrieveEmployeeList(String providerID) {
        EmployeeSearchRespoonse employeeSearchResponse = new EmployeeSearchRespoonse();
        try {
            
            ResponseEntity<Employee> responseEntity = restUtil.getEmployee("someurl", providerID);
       
            if(responseEntity.getStatusCode()!= HttpStatus.OK || responseEntity.getBody()==null){
                employeeSearchResponse.getErrors().add(new Error("500", "service not available"));
            }
            List<Employee> employeeListResponse = mappperMethod(Objects.requireNonNull(responseEntity.getBody()));
            employeeSearchResponse.getEmployeeList().addAll(employeeListResponse);
//            employeeSearchResponse.setEmployeeList(employeeListResponse);
            LOGGER.info("{}", employeeSearchResponse);
            return  employeeSearchResponse;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Error Occured retrieving  employee with providerID {} , exception is {}", providerID, ex);
            employeeSearchResponse.getErrors().add(new Error("500", "service not available"));
            return employeeSearchResponse;
        }

    }
```

if i use the getLis.addAll the object returned is with empty list only when I use set the object returns with list and its values

Comment: You don't keep a reference to the newly constructed list, so it is detached from the object you asked it from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `employeeList` (the instance variable) is `null`, then you make a new `ArrayList` each time `getEmployeeList` is called. You have two options. First, you could actually assign the `employeeList` in the `null` case.

```
public List<Employee> getEmployeeList() {
  if (employeeList == null){
    employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
  }
  return employeeList;
}
```

Second, and much preferred, simply initialize the `employeeList` properly in your constructor.

```
EmployeeSearchResponse() {
  employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
  ...
}
```

If `null` is not an actual valid value for this variable, then don't let it ever become `null` in the first place.